# How to authenticate a cognito user with access token and id token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been been able to setup cognito login with user pool external federated identity providers (Facebook and Google). This then gets me an access token and id token. I can then use those tokens with the [aws-sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html).

I was wondering if I can use those tokens to authenticate the user with [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) instead? As far as I can tell, you must use their username and password when authenticating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Facebook and Google are Identity Providers. Amazon Cognito User Pools is also an Identity Provider. Cognito Federated Identities uses Identity Providers (Facebook, Google, Cognito User Pools) to provide authentication.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of annoying having to use multiple libraries. My regular Cognito users login with amazon-cognito-identity-js, Facebook and Google users with amazon-cognito-auth-js and then both of them update their user attributes with aws-sdk.

Comment: I think that the problem is that Cognito is actually three different products with similar names. If Amazon had given unique names to each one, there would be less confusion.